# TypeScript | Почему, если объявить объект как объект, выдаёт ошибку

Tags: typescript, объекты

У меня есть код, который подключает класс **Human** из локального файла. Всё работает нормально. Также, я сделал **'Json-Serializer'**, для этого я создал объект, и  внутри него добавил массив **People**, чтобы использовать метод `push()`. Т.е., мой код работает, но если я к объявлению моего объекта добавлю `: object`, **то выдаёт ошибку уже сам текстовый редактор**.

Вот мой код:

```
// @ts-check
import Human from './human.class';
import { writeFile } from 'fs';

let objectToJSON = {
    People: <Human[]>[]
}

let names: string[]    = ["Владислав", "Роман",   "Всеволод", "Михаил", "Дарья",    "Александр", "Моника",  "Вадим", "Артём"]
let surnames: string[] = ["Борисов",   "Елисеев", "Грачев",   "Вдовин", "Корнеева", "Быков",     "Алешина", "Гуров", "Богомолов"]

names.forEach((name: string) => {
    objectToJSON.People.push(new Human(name, surnames[names.indexOf(name)], Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 10 + 1) + 10)))
})

writeFile(`${__dirname}/people.json`, JSON.stringify(objectToJSON), (err) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err.message);
    console.log(typeof objectToJSON);
    
})
```

И, если я к строчке `let objectToJSON = {` припишу `: object`, т.е. `let objectToJSON: object = {`, то мне выдаёт такую ошибку

> Property 'People' does not exist on type 'object'.

Объясните пожалуйста почему?

Правка:

> Я проверил тип `objectToJSON`, он говорит, что это **object**

Comment: _Я проверил тип objectToJSON, он говорит, что это object_ - как ты проверял?

Comment: @Grundy console.log(typeof objectToJSON);

Comment: `typeof` выводит js тип, он никак не связан с типами в TypeScript

Comment: @Grundy , тоесть, у `objectToJSON` не `object` тип? Тогда можно мне его тип как-нибудь инициализировать, как статично-типизированным?

Comment: он у тебя и так статично типизирован

Comment: Я конечно извиняюсь за такие вопросы, но как понять что он уже статично типизирован, я просто пост-`C#`ер, а на `TypeScript` у меня написана строка `let objectToJSON = {}`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121026/discussion-between-grundy-and-a-br2h).